# Jenkins thinBackup - include additional folder

Tags: jenkins

When using the thinBackup Jenkins plugin one can configure it to include additional files. It seems impossible to include whole additional folders though.

In our case (see screenshot below) it is adding the `secret.*` files properly but does fail to include the `secrets` folder (or in the case shown here the `.key` files in the `secrets` folder).

Are we configuring this wrong or is it just not possible to include arbitrary folders?
[image: Screenshot of Jenkins settings]

Answer (score 2):

I played around with regex and if you want to backup all the files in secrets folder, try below regex.
It works fine

```
^(.*\.xml)|^(secrets|.*\.key|.*\.KEY|.*\.Secret|.*\.secret|.*\.mac|.*\.MAC|.*\.seed|.*\.crumbSalt|.*\.consoleAnnotator|.*\.serverCookie|.*\-switch|whitelisted\-callables\.d|.*\.conf|filepath\-filters\.d|.*\.conf)$
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to use the vertical bar to represent a folder or subfolder. I believe the fix for your regex in the screenshot would be changing (secrets/.*.key) to:

```
(secrets|.*\.key)
```

Any further subfolders have a similar syntax, such as getting *.groovy from jenkins/scriptler/scripts/:

```
(scriptler|scripts|.*\.groovy)
```

Maybe you've already figured this out, but if not, I hope this helps.

Bill